# How does the proposal to designate 60% of Gaza's agricultural land as security buffer zones align with international law and norms?

Tags: israel, gaza, hamas

> On Tuesday, during a conference held in the Knesset to examine
> possibilities for postwar Gaza, Gamliel said: “At the end of the war,
> Hamas rule will collapse. There are no municipal authorities; the
> civilian population will be entirely dependent on humanitarian aid.
> There will be no work, and 60% of Gaza’s agricultural land will become
> security buffer zones.”

https://www.timesofisrael.com/israel-in-talks-with-congo-and-other-countries-on-gaza-voluntary-migration-plan/

Under whose proposal is the idea of designating 60% of Gaza's agricultural land as security buffer zones being considered? During a conference a person said that 60% of Gaza's agricultural land will become security buffer zone. It seems like he's referring to some proposal, but I haven't heard anything from this, and I would like to know from whom it comes from, because I am not sure it was a proposal that the U.S. supports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150633/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-ohwilleke).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How does the proposal to designate 60% of Gaza's agricultural land as
> security buffer zones align with international law and norms?

Maybe you could argue that one principle or another of international law or norms applied in some way, but this is, to a great extent, a unique situation and one not contemplated by the drafters of treaties and treatises on international law.

On one hand, Israel have sovereign authority over Gaza, so the default rule is that it has life and death authority over everything that happens there, without foreign interference in its internal affairs. Countries also have broad authority to protect their own national security.

On the other hand, Gaza is essentially a non-sovereign colony ruled by Israel but not having a final say over its own governance. Colonies and areas of political dependency without a say in the government that rules them are disfavored in modern Western political thought, but many countries have them anyway (e.g., the U.S. has the District of Columbia and Puerto Rico and the U.S. Virgin Islands, and Guam and American Samoa). Self-governance is a desirable thing for colonies of this kind, but international diplomats didn't complain too much, for example, during the long period of time when Hong Kong was under British rule without meaningful self-governance.

Certainly, there is no international law or norm that requires a country or colony to be capable of providing all of its own food locally. As a comment from JonathanReez to the OP notes, Gaza technologically incapable of growing enough food to feed the people who live there even with all of its current agricultural land.

But, international law and norms do require that the human rights of people in territory controlled by a sovereign country to be protected by the sovereign country in control of that territory, although only a few remedies are available to the international community if this obligation is not observed.

Removing the ability to generate one's own food and preventing food imports, resulting in the people of a territory starving to death, does violate international law and norms. But if people in a territory can feed themselves through some combination of importing food and growing their own, this isn't an international law issue.

Taking private property without compensation is also potentially an issue, but national security concerns sometimes override a country's obligation to do so. The economic value of agricultural land in Gaza, if its owners were compensated, probably isn't all that great in any case, if Israel choses to pay for it.

> Under whose proposal is the idea of designating 60% of Gaza's
> agricultural land as security buffer zones being considered?

I do not know the answer to this part of the question.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150652/discussion-on-answer-by-ohwilleke-how-does-the-proposal-to-designate-60-of-gaza); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - You saw the statement that "On the other hand, Gaza is essentially a non-sovereign colony ruled by Israel but not having a final say over its own governance" being very much in *favor* of Israel? OK.... While I cannot speak for the author of the answer by any means, if you were familiar with the general support for statehood or independence of Washington D.C. and Puerto Rico among left-leaning people in the U.S.A., I think you would probably see that that comparison does not throw a favorable light on Israel's actions in the Gaza Strip.

Comment: Why are there no references in this answer? How can you make a claim like "Israel have sovereign authority over Gaza" without providing any evidence? In actual fact Gaza is an [occupied territory](https://www.hrw.org/news/2023/10/27/how-does-international-humanitarian-law-apply-israel-and-gaza) and Israel does not have sovereign authority.

Comment: "The economic value of agricultural land in Gaza" is probably very low because Israel controls that economy and wants it to be low. It doesn't actually tell us any useful information.

Answer (score 2):

[**Lies, damned lies, and statistics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics) - the statement quoted in the OP might be technically true, but is mostly aimed at discrediting whatever arrangements Israel is proposing to ensure the mutual security of the Israels  and the Gazans.

[According to Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/israel-informs-arab-states-it-wants-buffer-zone-post-war-gaza-sources-2023-12-01/):

> A senior Israeli security source said the buffer zone idea was "being examined", adding: **"It is not clear at the moment how deep this will be and whether it could be 1 km or 2 km or hundreds of metres (inside Gaza)."**
>
> **Any encroachment into Gaza, which is about 40 km (25 miles) long and between about 5 km (3 miles) and 12 km (7.5 miles) wide, would cram its 2.3 million people into an even smaller area.**
>
> In Washington, an Israeli official said the Israeli defense establishment was talking about "some kind of security buffer on the Gaza side of the border so that Hamas cannot gather military capabilities close to the border and surprise Israel again."
>
> "It is a security measure, not a political one," the official said on condition of anonymity. "We do not intend to remain on the Gaza side of the border."

Assuming that Gaza is a rectangle, two sides of which border Israel, the security zone of 1 kilometer would take about 50 square kilometers, out of about 400 square kilometers area - that is about 12% of the territory. This is a lot, but whether it constitutes 60% of agricultural land is open to debate. It is also not clear what *security/buffer zone* really means - that it is totally inaccessible or that, e.g., it should not contain any buildings, so that any movements can be observed - in which case using it as an agricultural land is perfectly possible.

**Update**
Following up the discussion in the comments: the statement was made by the Israeli intelligence minister Gila Galmiel, who belongs to the faction advocating migration of Gazans to other Arab countries. It still however aims at dismissing the idea that Israel and Gaza could peacefully coexist. I think the caveats about this argument outlined above remain valid.

Comment: It's a statement made by an Israeli minister, in the Israeli parliament. How can it be trying to discredit and arrangment Israel (or the government thereof) is proposing?

Comment: Also downvoted for this comment; "...the mutual security of the Israels and the Gazans." The security of Gazan citizens has clearly not been on anyone in the Israeli Government's mind since day 1.

Comment: @Darren you are right, she likely has a different agenda - but an agenda nonetheless.

Comment: Comment to your update: Is there a "faction"? Is not the relocation of all Gazans pretty much a national policy now (stated or implied)? C.f. Illegal settelements in The West Bank etc.

Comment: @Darren if it is a *stated policy* please link a statement. If it is an *implied policy* - isn't it essentially your guess? I don't see how West Bank is related to buffer zone in Gaza - let's stick to the topic.

Comment: There was a nice PBS documentary "Failure at the Fence" which explained how there is a cleared area inside the fence where remote-controlled machine guns are supposed to fire on anyone approaching (the person they interviewed said she refrained from firing at a few children wandered near). So that sounds closer to "totally inaccessible".

Comment: @OwenReynolds I am not sure whether [this is the full transcript](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/frontline/documentary/failure-at-the-fence/transcript/) of the documentary, but it doesn't confirm your claim that *machine guns are supposed to fire on anyone approaching*. Otherwise, machine guns at the border is not a rarity anywhere in the world

Comment: @RogerV. - The claim is that they only will fire at anyone who gets too close to the fence if they see "a weapon and a threat," and only after a warning shot. Now, whether you believe that they always follow these rules is another question (I don't).

Comment: @Obie2.0 most people beliefs in this case depend on whether they like Jews or not, so I prefer not to touch this subject. On the other hand, I wonder how the western practices differ - say, the marine guards in Mediterranean or near the Florida coast, Mexican border, European borders with Russia and Turkey, Northern Ireland.

Comment: In Failure at the Fence in the part with Rotem Horowitz, she says "usually if someone's getting close to the fence, we use it to kind of not shoot at them, but shoot near them, to kind of scare them away." In other words, no one is allowed to be in the security zone.

Comment: @RogerV. Israelis and Jews aren't the same group. Note that people's opinion depends equally as much on whether they like Muslims or not.

Comment: @user253751 - I fear that you two are both correct. In theory, people should be reasoning based on the facts and on consistent principles of human rights. In practice, it often comes down to whether they view Israelis or Palestinians (or indeed Jews or Muslims) as more sympathetic.

Comment: @user253751 *Note that people's opinion depends equally as much on whether they like Muslims or not.* - note that Muslims, Arabs, and Palestinians are not the same thing either. But I disagree about treating this as a choice between Jews and Arabs - for most Anti-Israeli westerners it is simply about their dislike of the Jews, regardless of what the issue is. A simple litmus test is support dor Hamas - Hamas is certainly bad for Palestinians and has nothing ro do with western values, but it does hurt the Jews.

Comment: @RogerV. I disagree strongly. For most Anti-Palestinian westerners it's about their dislike of the Muslims, regardless of the issue. For most Anti-Israeli westerners it's about them not liking holocausts and genocides, regardless of race or religion. (Did you know that the words "Shoah" and "Nakba" have the same meaning?) But it's very much in Israel's favour to pretend to be the victim of widespread antisemitism, and they're able to spread this message widely thanks to certain media groups.

Comment: @user253751 Shoah and Nakba may have the same semantic value, but they do not mean the same thing: **Nakba forced hundreds of thousands of Palestinians out of their homes, Shoah was a systematic murder of 6,000,000+ people**. This is about how many Jews are there in Israel. This is more than the number of the Palestinian refugees with all their descendants. You simply do not understand meaning of words "genocide" and "Holocaust".

Comment: @RogerV. Way to respond to a tangent and ignore the actual point. Feeling the need to embolden a full 1/3 of your comment is the online equivalent of shouting in the hopes that shouting makes you more correct.

Comment: @user253751 these are just general phrases and ad-hominen attacks.