# Independent confirmations of the Israeli project for resettlement of Gazans

Tags: armed-conflict, israel, palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza

The Times of Israel reports in [*Israel in talks with Congo and other countries on Gaza ‘voluntary migration’ plan*](https://www.timesofisrael.com/israel-in-talks-with-congo-and-other-countries-on-gaza-voluntary-migration-plan/) that members of the Israeli government are arguing for resettlement of Gazans in another Muslim country. Specifically, it claims that this has been discussed by the Netanyahu's Likud party and that Netanyahu shares this position:

> Last Monday, Netanyahu told a Likud faction meeting that he is working to facilitate the voluntary migration of Gazans to other countries.
>
> “Our problem is [finding] countries that are willing to absorb Gazans, and we are working on it,” he said.
>
> The prime minister was responding to Likud MK Danny Danon, who claimed that “the world is already discussing the possibilities of voluntary immigration,” though the idea has been roundly rejected by the international community.
>
> The far-right Religious Zionism and Otzma Yehudit parties, headed by Finance Minister Bezalel Smotrich and National Security Minister Itamar Ben Gvir, respectively, have backed the plans for migration.

It also quotes statements by the Israeli Intelligence Minister Gila Galmiel, discussed in [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/83685/38304).

However, I couldn't find independent confirmation of this report, except the condemnations of the right-wing Smotrich and Ben Gvir: [here](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2024/01/04/eu-countries-condemn-israeli-far-right-ministers-call-to-resettle-gazas-palestinians) and [here](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/us-slams-israeli-ministers-statements-resettlement-palestinians-outside-gaza-2024-01-02/).

Given that The Times of Israel is right-leaning, and the controversial nature of such claims, I would like to see an independent confirmation from credible sources.

**Update**
More recent reports suggest that the proposal is still largely confined to Ben Gvir and Smotrich, although more forceful denunciation by the government would be welcome.

[*Politico*'s rather expanded article on Netanyahu](https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2024/01/08/netanyahu-israeli-leader-losing-control-00134146) only says:

> Ben-Gvir and Smotrich have gone further, reportedly calling for the supposedly voluntary migration of Palestinians out of Gaza and future Israeli settlement and occupation of the territory. The State Department has blasted such comments as “ inflammatory and irresponsible.”

[*Ynetnews*, in connection to the ongoing Blinken's visit in the region, reports](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/sjpq8qdot):

> **The U.S. is expected to urge Israel to publicly reject proposals for the voluntary migration of Gaza residents**, as the IDF maintains security in the Strip and regulates the movement of residents from south to north.
>
> **President Isaac Herzog told NBC in an interview Sunday that calls for Gaza residents' voluntary migration are not official Israeli policy.** He emphasized Israel's democratic nature, where a diversity of ideas is expected and freedom of expression is integral to the national ethos. In a 30-minister cabinet, separate from the security cabinet, each minister is free to voice individual opinions.

Comment: There have also been statements by Netanyahu regarding how he's not opposed to it, it's just that other world states have refused to take Palestinians in.

Comment: @einpoklum I get that much from the TTOI article. I want credible references, not radical right-/left-wing musings.

Comment: I would say that The Times of Israel being right-leaning does not make them unreliable. If anything, more credible. Which would be its bias, to denounce a plan (note the quotes about "voluntary migration") from a right wing government?

Comment: @SJuan76 Correction - this is not a plan from the right-wing government, but musings of two right-wing extremists. *Credible* is just another word for *belief*, as distinct from *fact* - which can be established from the official government statements or by comparing to other sources. TTOF motives are open to guesses - it might try to present it as a mainstream view, or argue that buffer zone cannot solve anything and resettlement is the only solution.

Comment: Voting not to close - It's a simple Q asking for confirmations on a report / statement from other sources.

Answer (score 8):

> Given that the Times of Israel is right-leanign, and the controversial nature of such claims, I would like to see an independent confirmation form creditable sources.

- **[Israel's allies warn against displacing Palestinians in Gaza to places like Canada](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/israel-allies-warn-against-displacement-palestinians-gaza-1.7073734)**
- **[EU and UK slam Israeli ministers’ call for ‘voluntary emigration’ from Gaza Strip](https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-uk-slam-inflammatory-call-by-israeli-minister-smotrich-voluntary-emigration-of-gaza/)**
- **[Senior Israel ministers call for ‘voluntary emigration’ of Palestinians, building of Jewish settlements in Gaza](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20240102-senior-israel-ministers-call-for-voluntary-emigration-of-palestinians-building-of-jewish-settlements-in-gaza/)**

> Last Monday, Netanyahu told a Likud faction meeting that he is working to facilitate the **voluntary** migration of Gazans to other countries.

I think the concern is how "voluntary" the emigration would be.  Otherwise Israel has long encouraged Palestinian emigration from both Gaza and the West bank dating back to 1967 when they captured these territories.

- **[Migration of refugees and non-refugees to Amman, 1948-1977](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12311017/)**

> In 1967 refugees from Gaza and the West Bank constituted 59.2% of the total number of migrants to Amman.

- August 2019 - **[Israeli Right Resurrects ‘Voluntary Transfer’ of Palestinians, Despite 50 Years of Failure](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2019-08-25/ty-article/.premium/right-wing-resurrects-voluntary-transfer-of-palestinians-despite-50-years-of-fail/0000017f-e22a-df7c-a5ff-e27a35aa0000)**

This administration's 'voluntary emigration' effort first appeared mid November.

From Nov 14, 2023

- **[Israeli minister calls for voluntary emigration of Gazans](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/israeli-minister-calls-voluntary-emigration-gazans-2023-11-14/)**
- **[Palestinians Furious With Israeli Officials’ Call for Voluntary Emigration of Gazans](https://themedialine.org/top-stories/palestinians-furious-with-israeli-officials-call-for-voluntary-emigration-of-gazans/)**

Comment: This merely reiterates the information on Smotrich snd Ben Gvir, some lunks are even the same as in the OP. There's no confirmation about the Likud, Netanyahu and government in general.

Comment: @RogerV,  your source is from Jan 3 2024,   My source has Smotrich saying the same thing in Nov, 2023 with the Palestinians reactions in Nov.  My three sources reacting to your Jan 3 source all add more detail while referencing the latest discussions,  Including actions taken by Netanyahu in support of this long supported Israeli position.  Sorry it wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: please quote the relevant passages - perhaps, you messed up the links.

Answer (score 1):

The Times of Israel reports that the Congo categorically reports that they are in talks with Israel for the resettlement of Gazan refugees.

Reading between the lines, I expect that there wwre some exploratory talks whoch were blown completely out of the water when they were publicised. Given the strength of feeling of the global south in supporting Palestine, I expect the Congo came under a lot of pressure to deny there were any talks for ethnic cleansing by another name, or a second Nakba as the Palestinians are calling it.

Comment: Could you provide a reference?